# 2d array list is automatically getting updated for all 2d array in the list with the last supplied 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

i have the following code in which whenever i pass a new 2d array to the list, the existing 2d arrays in the list gets automatically updated with the 2d array just passed to the constructor.

```
private List <Timetable> timetablelist;
public TimetableManager() {
        
        this.timetablelist = new ArrayList<Timetable>(); 
         
    }
String[][] data = new String[6][10];
String tchridcls;
try{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    
                    Object[] lines = br.lines().toArray();
                    int i=0,j=0;
                    
                    while(i<lines.length){
                        String[] row = lines[i].toString().split(",",-1);
                        
                        tchridcls=row[0];
                        
                        data[j][0]=row[1];
                        
                        data[j][1]=row[2];
                        data[j][2]=row[3];
                        data[j][3]=row[4];
                        data[j][4]=row[5];
                        data[j][5]=row[6];
                        data[j][6]=row[7];
                        data[j][7]=row[8];
                        data[j][8]=row[9];
                        data[j][9]=row[10];
                        
                        i++;
                        j++;
                       
                        if(i%6==0){
                            
                            
                        Timetable t = new Timetable(data,tchridcls);
                        timetablelist.add(t);
                        j=0;
                        
                        }}}
```

This is the timetable class

```
public class Timetable {
    private String[][]  timetable = new String[6][10];
    private String teacherid_class;
    public Timetable(String[][] timetable, String teacherid_class){
        this.teacherid_class = teacherid_class;
        
        this.timetable = timetable;
        
    }
public String getteacherid_class(){
    return teacherid_class;
}

public String[][] gettimetable(){
    return timetable;}
```

I have already checked this thing that the issue arises after passing the `data[][]` to the constructor. It for some reason updates the data[][] 2d array of all the existing objects in the list  with the newly supplied data[][] 2d array.

This issue has taken so much of time plz help me!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public Timetable(String[][] timetable, String teacherid_class){
    this.teacherid_class = teacherid_class;
    this.timetable = timetable;    // all timetables reference the same object
}
```

With your current code you are just creating a reference to the same 2d array`(this=that)`. When you update `data`, all the references are updated, since they are all the same object.

Change the constructor as shown below, so it creates a **deep copy** of the 2d array. This would lead to the creation of a a new object, a deep clone of data, and not just a (*mirror-copy*) reference to it.

Now each `timetable` will indeed be a new object, and following mofications of `data` won't affect them.

```
public Timetable(String[][] tt, String tic)
{
   this.teacherid_class = tic;
   this.timetable = Arrays.stream(tt).map(el -> el.clone()).toArray($ -> tt.clone());
 }
```

*I edited the names just for readability*

Comment: What's up, Aran? Great post. When I was teaching some years ago, I had to teach the concept of deep copy to the author of the book I was using to teach; and he had a PhD. Shamefully, his newest edition never gave me any credit. This is why some many new devs don't understand this concept; the ones writing text books don't know them.

Comment: @hfontanez so glad to hear this from you mate! how are you doing overseas? From my experience in the old continent, and as a "somehow" recent student (finished my Master's degree now 8 years ago), I cannot but agree with what you're saying. One of my teachers stated that java's clone was always deep, the others just merely commented the concept. As a result: we became engineers that weren't properly taught what a shallow copy is, and what a deep copy is. Just like if a medic wasn't properly taught what's the difference between a vein and an artery. Truly sad. And this is reflected, as you say

Comment: On the new developers' knowledge in this area. The guidelines are short and clear, but they aren't passed to new engineers. Shallow copy  of primitives, immutables --> OK ;Otherwise, a deep-copy is required. Multidimensional arrays also have to be "deep copied", as they are just a list of variables, each referring to a one-dimensional array; Either use some stream command as the shown here, or loop through the outer array and clone the elements from there (which are indeed the inner array).

Comment: It's a longer story... the shorter story, he who shall remain nameless sort of argued that his book example was correct. I provided him with a detail example as to why he was wrong and a few lines explaining the concept. He was confident. The shame is that, when textbooks publish information, most will tend to take it as gospel (since they do go through "strict" review process. Anyway, good to see you again thru these parts!